# Are there alternatives to the WP-G1000 silicone grease?

Tags: nikon, equipment-recommendation, maintenance, underwater, weather-sealing

The Nikon AW1 (and other Nikon 1 series products which require this silicone grease) are all long discontinued. This extends to the silicone grease, a key product to maintaining the camera/underwater housing’s o rings.

Since this product is no longer produced, it seems like looking for a similar product elsewhere is the only reasonable option. What suitable alternative products exist, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nikon grease can still be found; Ace Photo in VA says they have it in stock.

But I'm fairly certain there is nothing particularly special about it. Fantasea O-ring grease would be a suitable alternative. Or almost any other silicone grease listed as suitable for rubber o-rings/seals... but you want to avoid thicker versions like super-lube; they are harder to work with for applications like this.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for this answer! How is super-lube (or equivalent) harder to work with? Are their viscosity/thickness _really_ difficult to work with, or do they not like being pressed into gasket channels, etc.? Just curious. This is fascinating to me.

Comment: @scottbb, the super lube is very thick and tends to leave too much behind which collects grit/dust. In this kind of application the silicone grease is used as more of a *rubber conditioner*, if that makes sense.

Comment: Understood, completely. Definitely, one is an _attractant_, as opposed to an almost "moisturizer". I get the sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and probably going to be buying the one from ace photo, however it may turn out to be an incorrect listing (meaning there may actually be none). And besides, I think it only listed like 2 as available so if someone buys those, then there wouldn’t be any anymore. 

If there isn’t anything special about it, that’s definitely reassuring!